# Spotfire - choose categories to be displayed in Line chart

Tags: spotfire

Is it possible to choose only few categories to be included in line chart without using filters?

Example:

I have Spotfire table which shows sum of fruits sold.

[image]

I want only apples and oranges to be displayed in my line chart without using filters.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options:

If you want to hide watermelon rows, You can limit the data at the visualization level using visualization>properties>show/hide items or by limiting the rows using visualization>properties>Data>Limit data using expression:

```
[fruit] in ("Apples","Oranges")
```

or

```
[fruit] <> "Watermelons"
```

To limit data at the axis level, say you want to display Apples and Oranges and group all the others, you can use a custom expression in your axis. For example:

```
if ([fruit] in ("Apples", "Oranges"),[fruit],"Other Fruits")
```

Comment: @jleviaguirre- Thank you! Your custom expression solution helped me in finding the solution that I needed.